# Hostapd Daemon for two Wireless Adaptors on same board

Tags: hostapd

I am working on a wireless Adaptor APIs using C++. 
I want to set two APs (two wireless adaptors on same board) configuration by running two different hostapd daemon using two different hostapd.conf files.

In linux command line we can call #hostapd -d /etc/hostapd.conf

How I can link my modified hostapd.conf file to hostapd daemon using C++.

john